# Ajax requests work for 30 seconds

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a program that has some functions that uses ajax. I noticed some time, that all ajax only funcioal during the 30 seconds of inactivity the page. This is weird. When this time expires, the ajax stops working and every component that uses this request does not work anymore.

example:

I have a DataTable with a button that opens a dialog one. By default the primefaces ajax components are active, when I click on the button opens a dialog. only for that to happen if the page is idle for 30 seconds.
Configured session timeout over yet still have no idea where the problem is.

Note: This happens throughout the project, not only in a few pages.
Thank you.

Comment: Any JS errors in the console? Press F12 in Chrome/Firefox>=23/IE>=9 to see it. Perhaps you've somewhere a `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` which executed a function which in turn contained a JS syntax error which in turn caused the whole JS context to fail?

Comment: this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces:1

Comment: Okay, there's the cause :) Now yet to understand and fix it. Are you manually including JS files? If so, which ones? Is jQuery also among them? If so, why exactly?

Comment: I understand that JS is the cause, but do not use JS directly. Use only primefaces, which in turn, seem to work in JS.

Comment: Please answer the questions in my previous comment. Are you manually including JS files? Yes or no? In other words, do you have for example `<script src="jquery.js">` or `<h:outputScript name="jquery.js">` anywhere in your page? If yes, which files exactly?

Comment: I not include any file in the page, or the entire project.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps the problem is in your browser. Try clearing its cache. Which browser and which PF version are you using by the way?

Comment: i make the test. I using primefaces 3.5 with chrome 29.0

Comment: Okay. Press F12 and open *Network* tab and then click *XHR* in bottom. Is something happening in there? Yes? How exactly does the request and response look like? And, do you possibly have servlet filters in your webapp which are (perhaps unintentionally) also acting on those ajax requests? Yes? What exactly are those filters supposed to do?

Comment: I noticed that the ajax call, lasts as long as the open connection to the database. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

This question was probably asked ages ago. But I ran into a similar problem and got stuck trying to find bugs in my code for ages. Turns out the real bug was from my php.ini file. PHP sets *max_execution_time* to 30 seconds by default, you can either tweak your php.ini file to allow greater time or simply add the below code to the beginning of your php script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
```

By default *max_execution_time* is set to 30 seconds by PHP, setting the value to 0 removes the time restraint and allows the ajax script to keep running as long as the browser window stays alive.

Comment: This question is about ajax, jsf and Primefaces, **not php**