# Ajax get request stops working after some seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX for a chat service on my site.

I Use the AJAX script to update the chat area with new lines of chat that is written to a text file every one second.

Everything works as expected, but when there is inactivity on the page for 50 seconds, the AJAX get request fails to populate the chat-area with the chat lines; it just stops working like AJAX = ansyncroniously.

I have to reload the page to get the new chat lines.

Below is the code I'm currently using:

```
//Updates the chat
function updateChat() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {
            'state': state,
            'file': file
        },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.text != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
                    $('#chat-box').append($(" " + data.text[i] + " "));
                }
                document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
            }
            instanse = false;
            state = data.state;
            setTimeout('updateChat()', 1);
        },
    });
}
```

and on the calling `index.php` page I use:

```
var chat = new Chat("chat1.txt");
    chat.init();
    chat.updateChat();

var name = "janedoe34";
```

can't figure out why it stops working.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console? Also a request every second to a server-side page is a lot.... 5 clients that's 300 requests every minute. It could also be possible the server/host cannot deal with that amount of requests in such a short time.

Comment: You should only call `updateChat` when you have an ajax response, so *within* the success callback, otherwise you'll be queuing requests. Also, don't pass a string to `setTimeout`, but just `updateChat` without parentheses.

Comment: **Trincot** has made me notice something else too.... `setTimeout('updateChat()', 1);` = 1 millisecond.... not 1 second. 1000 is 1 second but as  **Trincot** pointed out it should be `setTimeout(updateChat, 1);` or `setTimeout(updateChat, 1000);` if you want to run this after 1 second rather than every millisecond and moved into the callback success.

Comment: If am not making request to the server every second there's no way to auto update the chatbox with new lines of chat from other users...

Comment: No one says you cannot make a request every second, but you're asking for issues if you don't first process the response before requesting again. Think how annoying it is to ask your partner "how do you feel", and you don't wait for the answer, but just keep repeating the question? One or both is bound to get nuts.

Comment: I have done that...  But it isn't working as expected..  Still stops updating the chat area with new lines after some time of inactivity...  It just as if the script is suspended after some seconds

Comment: If you want a instant chat then I would recommend you look into using websockets and nodejs if available to you but I understand why you have the ajax on a timeout, I'm just trying to explain it's a lot of requests in a short period of time but fine providing your host/server can deal with it and would help if you had the call in the correct place with the correct time set "one second" and not "one millisecond" **Edit:** Open your browser console and check for errors.

Comment: Am new to JS, going into node to develop a chat in few weeks is like a long shot ... Can you point me in any direction?

Answer (score 2):

after scouring stackoverflow for answers without luck, I saw similar questions like this one - [Ajax requests work for 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919013/ajax-requests-work-for-30-seconds) but like others, have seen there were no answers.

it turns out the solution was to tweak my php.ini file to allow max execution time to exceed 30 seconds or just add the below code to the beginning of my PHP script;

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
```

by default max_execution_time is set to 30 seconds by PHP, setting the value to 0 removes the time restraint and allows the ajax script to keep running.